# IOS4 Clear cache bug?! with "Add to Home Screen" apps and localStorage

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

we've got an App going live very shortly but I've discovered what looks like an IOS4 bug with Settings --> Safari --> Clear Cache.

Our app is authorized then used by, going to the website in Safari, authorizing, this creates a localStorage key then the user can launch in app-mode (from home screen) and the localStorage key is picked up.

This works fine in IOS5 and works fine in IOS4. UNTIL!!! You delete your cache, then the iPhone disallows your website (based on it's URL I'm assuming) to create any future localStorage Keys.

Each Home screen icon, has its own localStorage SET of key/values,

I.E

If I add a localStorage value from myurl1.com, add to home screen, clear cache, load, it fails

then if I do it from myurl2.com, (with same key), I can successfully load the newest home screen icon but still not the last.

Anyway, my issue is, Once a user clears their cache there appears to be no way for them to EVER launch the app from the home screen again as its permanently disallowed our website from creating more localStorage keys..

What do I Do?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried debugging that eg. with Weinre (good online version: http://debug.phonegap.com). I mean whether there are any errors thrown, it'd be good to see them here.

We had same kind of problem, but it was related to browsing in private mode, so it's probably not the situation in your case.

Otherwise, I've never seen this happening. localStorage has always worked just fine, no matter whether the cache is flushed or not.

Comment: yeh i encountred the private browsing issue, managed to fix that, (well actually theres no way around it, you just have to tell the user to disable it). Thansk for your help ill have a look